# Ignore an Empty Request Body?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

After writing tests for my REST API (built using Spring Boot), I realised that, even when the request body is not used (*see below*), calling the endpoint with a request body succeeds–effectively, Spring ignores the body.

This is not a huge issue, but I was wondering what philosophy I should approach this with:

- Should I fail when passed an unexpected body (when do not expect any)?
- If so, is this configurable in Spring so that there is strict checking of body/parameters?
- Finally, beyond personal preference and/or experience, is there a good way of deciding this, or should I simply use 'if it isn't broken, don't fix it' as my mantra?

---

```java
@PatchMapping(value = "/products/{pid}/sell")
public TxDTO sell(@NotBlank @PathVariable("pid") String pid,
                  @NotNull @RequestParam Float price)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't think too much into this. Technically, ignoring the unexpected body doesn't violate any software development principles. Even though this might be something that makes you feel uncomfortable personally in the context of your project, you might want to consider other scenarios where there's a filter or servlet sitting in front of your `@RestController` doing some additional stuff you're not aware of.

The point is this is not a feature you should turn off globally nor it is worth spending time implementing custom code to turn it off locally for a single endpoint :).

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right, there's no reason to be spending time thinking this :-)